# Digital tuner remote control software for linux?

Tags: linux, remote-control

I'm searching for **linux** software to "remote-control" a [Frontier Silicon-based](http://www.frontier-silicon.com/digital-radio-solutions) FM / DAB / Internet Radio Receiver via (W-)LAN. I've already found software for Android/iOS ("[Undok](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frontier_silicon.fsirc.dok2&hl=de)") and Win 10 ("[RadioRemote](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/radioremote/9nblggh4qp9q)" and "[FSRadio-Remote](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fs-remote/)") but nothing for Linux in general. There are some APIs available for [PHP](https://github.com/flammy/fsapi/) (see also [flammi's fsapi-remote for a web-based gui](https://github.com/flammy/fsapi-remote)) or [Python](https://github.com/zhelev/python-fsapi) as well as a [openHAB binding](https://github.com/openhab/openhab1-addons/wiki/Frontier-Silicon-Radio-Binding), but (AFAIK) no stand-alone application.